# Spring boot JPA specification find by @Column name

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a service that must be able to have a configurable username column in its User field, i.e. different columns can be treated by the service as the "username" (i.e. the actual username column, the ID column etc.). It is a strange requirement to have, but legacy support is a strange thing as you all know by now :)

I've tried to tackle this in a following way, my configuration file contains the name of the column that will be treated as the username, and then that value is used with JPA specifications to find the User (my repository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor).

The code looks something like this:

```
public UserEntity getUserByUsername(String username) {
       String columnName = configuration.getUsernameColumn();
       return userRepository.findOne((root, query, builder) ->
                builder.and(builder.equal(root.<String>get(columnName), username)));
}
```

This should work fine... However there is a catch, the column name is specified as the actual column name in the database, and the JPA specification seems to expect field name to be specified,  not the database column. My entity is annotated as:

```
@Column(name = "USER_NAME", length = 100)
private String userName;
```

So when I try to find the User by searching for "USER_NAME", my code throws an exception because it expected to find a "USER_NAME" field, not column in the database.

I know that the obvious solution is putting "userName" in the configuration instead, however that is not an option. Another way to do this is by using reflection, but that would a last resort approach. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Form the given details what I understood is username - [ID, username, ...] . And we want to specify which col to be queried from with the help of configuration. If so I think once you get the config data why not write a "Switch" statement - 

ID - findById
userName - findByUsername 

and so on. I am not sure but I think this might be a solution.

Comment: It is a solution, it is actually how we decided to make it work for now. The issue is that at the moment almost 20 columns can be set as the "username" column, so we were hoping for a cleaner, more concise solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the another solution can be the criteria query. Pass the column and the searchString and build the criteria query.

Reference : https://eng.zemosolabs.com/dynamic-multi-column-search-with-jpa-criteria-5720fedf13d3